# On start of the script, all three elements are visible. Is it possible to only show the elements of the option selected

Tags: javascript, html

Within this html code there are 3 options that should be handled with a script. The problem is that all the items will be shown per default when the page loads and thus are visible on the start of the script.
Is there a way to hide them and only show them after the script executes?

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".ios13-segmented-control").on("change", function() {
    $(".ios13-segmented-control .option input").each(function(i) {
      if ($(this).is(":checked")) $(".ios13-segmented-control .selection").css(
        "transform", "translateX(" + ($(this).outerWidth() * i) + "px)");
    });
  });
});

function check_value(fieldvalue) {
  switch (fieldvalue) {
    case 1:
      document.getElementByClassName("option").innerHTML = "Khar";
      break;
    case 2:
      document.getElementByClassName("option").innerHTML = "<h1>Santacruz</h1>";
      break;
    case 3:
      document.getElementByClassName("option").innerHTML = "<h1>Andheri</h1>";
      break;
  }
}
```

```css
body,
html {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  text-rendering: geometricPrecision;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
  font-family: -apple-system, system-ui, BlinkMacSystemFont, "Segoe UI", Roboto, "Helvetica Neue", Arial, sans-serif;
  -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch !important;
  touch-action: manipulation !important;
  -webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)
}

body {
  display: flex
}

* {
  box-sizing: border-box
}

body main {
  margin-top: 20px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto
}

label {
  cursor: inherit
}

.ios13-segmented-control {
  --background: rgba(239, 239, 240, 1);
  background: var(--background);
  border-radius: 9px;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 2.3px;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  display: grid;
  grid-auto-flow: column;
  grid-auto-columns: 1fr;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  user-select: none
}

.ios13-segmented-control .option {
  position: relative;
  cursor: pointer
}

.ios13-segmented-control .option:hover input:not(:checked)+label span,
.ios13-segmented-control .option:active input:not(:checked)+label span,
.ios13-segmented-control .option:focus input:not(:checked)+label span {
  opacity: .2
}

.ios13-segmented-control .option:active input:not(:checked)+label span {
  transform: scale(.95)
}

.ios13-segmented-control .option label {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 3px 6vmin;
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0);
  font-weight: 500;
  color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 1);
  font-size: 14px
}

.ios13-segmented-control .option label::before,
.ios13-segmented-control .option label::after {
  content: '';
  width: 1px;
  background: rgba(142, 142, 147, .15);
  position: absolute;
  top: 14%;
  bottom: 14%;
  border-radius: 10px;
  will-change: background;
  -webkit-transition: background .2s ease;
  transition: background .2s ease
}

.ios13-segmented-control .option label::before {
  left: 0;
  transform: translateX(-.5px)
}

.ios13-segmented-control .option label::after {
  right: 0;
  transform: translateX(.5px)
}

.ios13-segmented-control .option:first-of-type {
  grid-column: 1;
  grid-row: 1;
  box-shadow: none
}

.ios13-segmented-control .option:first-of-type label::before {
  opacity: 0
}

.ios13-segmented-control .option:last-of-type label::after {
  opacity: 0
}

.ios13-segmented-control .option input {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  -moz-appearance: none;
  appearance: none;
  outline: none;
  border: none;
  opacity: 0
}

.ios13-segmented-control .selection {
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 1);
  border: .5px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.04);
  box-shadow: 0 3px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12), 0 3px 1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.04);
  border-radius: 7px;
  grid-column: 1;
  grid-row: 1;
  z-index: 2;
  will-change: transform;
  -webkit-transition: transform .2s ease;
  transition: transform .2s ease
}

.ios13-segmented-control .option label span {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 2;
  -webkit-transition: all .2s ease;
  transition: all .2s ease;
  will-change: transform
}

.ios13-segmented-control .option input:checked+label::before,
.ios13-segmented-control .option input:checked+label::after {
  background: var(--background);
  z-index: 1
}

.ios13-segmented-control .option input:checked+label {
  cursor: default
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<body ontouchstart="">
  <main>
    <div class="ios13-segmented-control"> <span class="selection"></span>
      <div class="option"> <input type="radio" id="khar" name="sample" value="khar" checked> <label for="khar"><span>Khar</span></label></div>
      <div class="option"> <input type="radio" id="santacruz" name="sample" value="santacruz"> <label for="santacruz"><span>Santacruz</span></label></div>
      <div class="option"> <input type="radio" id="andheri" name="sample" value="andheri"> <label for="andheri"><span>Andheri</span></label></div>
    </div>
    <div class="khar selectt"> <br> <strong style="font-size: 24px; font-weight: 700; line-height:30px;">Khar</strong><br></div>
    <div class="santacruz selectt"> <br> <strong style="font-size: 24px; font-weight: 700; line-height:30px;">Santacruz</strong><br></div>
    <div class="andheri selectt"> <br> <strong style="font-size: 24px; font-weight: 700; line-height:30px;">Andheri</strong><br></div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      $(document).ready(function() {
        $('input[type="radio"]').click(function() {
          var inputValue = $(this).attr("value");
          var targetBox = $("." + inputValue);
          $(".selectt").not(targetBox).hide();
          $(targetBox).show();
        });
      });
    </script>
  </main>
</body>
```

Comment: Yes, it is possible. Instead of just posting a wall of code, you could have made a [mre].

Answer (score 0):

You can directly give them a css property of display:none

```
<element style="display:none"></element>
```

Answer (score 0):

well, looks like you have everything you need at hand, the solution is quite straite-forward: to

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('input[type="radio"]').click(function() {
    var inputValue = $(this).attr("value");
    var targetBox = $("." + inputValue);
    $(".selectt").not(targetBox).hide();
    $(targetBox).show();
  });
});
```

add manual hiding:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('input[type="radio"]').each(function(index, element) {
    var inputValue = $(this).attr("value");
    var targetBox = $("." + inputValue);
    $(targetBox).hide();
  }).click(function() {
    var inputValue = $(this).attr("value");
    var targetBox = $("." + inputValue);
    $(".selectt").not(targetBox).hide();
    $(targetBox).show();
  });
});
```

Simple substitution in your code gives:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".ios13-segmented-control").on("change", function() {
    $(".ios13-segmented-control .option input").each(function(i) {
      if ($(this).is(":checked")) $(".ios13-segmented-control .selection").css(
        "transform", "translateX(" + ($(this).outerWidth() * i) + "px)");
    });
  });
});

function check_value(fieldvalue) {
  switch (fieldvalue) {
    case 1:
      document.getElementByClassName("option").innerHTML = "Khar";
      break;
    case 2:
      document.getElementByClassName("option").innerHTML = "<h1>Santacruz</h1>";
      break;
    case 3:
      document.getElementByClassName("option").innerHTML = "<h1>Andheri</h1>";
      break;
  }
}
```

```css
body,
html {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  text-rendering: geometricPrecision;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
  font-family: -apple-system, system-ui, BlinkMacSystemFont, "Segoe UI", Roboto, "Helvetica Neue", Arial, sans-serif;
  -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch !important;
  touch-action: manipulation !important;
  -webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)
}

body {
  display: flex
}

* {
  box-sizing: border-box
}

body main {
  margin-top: 20px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto
}

label {
  cursor: inherit
}

.ios13-segmented-control {
  --background: rgba(239, 239, 240, 1);
  background: var(--background);
  border-radius: 9px;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 2.3px;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  display: grid;
  grid-auto-flow: column;
  grid-auto-columns: 1fr;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  user-select: none
}

.ios13-segmented-control .option {
  position: relative;
  cursor: pointer
}

.ios13-segmented-control .option:hover input:not(:checked)+label span,
.ios13-segmented-control .option:active input:not(:checked)+label span,
.ios13-segmented-control .option:focus input:not(:checked)+label span {
  opacity: .2
}

.ios13-segmented-control .option:active input:not(:checked)+label span {
  transform: scale(.95)
}

.ios13-segmented-control .option label {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 3px 6vmin;
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0);
  font-weight: 500;
  color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 1);
  font-size: 14px
}

.ios13-segmented-control .option label::before,
.ios13-segmented-control .option label::after {
  content: '';
  width: 1px;
  background: rgba(142, 142, 147, .15);
  position: absolute;
  top: 14%;
  bottom: 14%;
  border-radius: 10px;
  will-change: background;
  -webkit-transition: background .2s ease;
  transition: background .2s ease
}

.ios13-segmented-control .option label::before {
  left: 0;
  transform: translateX(-.5px)
}

.ios13-segmented-control .option label::after {
  right: 0;
  transform: translateX(.5px)
}

.ios13-segmented-control .option:first-of-type {
  grid-column: 1;
  grid-row: 1;
  box-shadow: none
}

.ios13-segmented-control .option:first-of-type label::before {
  opacity: 0
}

.ios13-segmented-control .option:last-of-type label::after {
  opacity: 0
}

.ios13-segmented-control .option input {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  -moz-appearance: none;
  appearance: none;
  outline: none;
  border: none;
  opacity: 0
}

.ios13-segmented-control .selection {
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 1);
  border: .5px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.04);
  box-shadow: 0 3px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12), 0 3px 1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.04);
  border-radius: 7px;
  grid-column: 1;
  grid-row: 1;
  z-index: 2;
  will-change: transform;
  -webkit-transition: transform .2s ease;
  transition: transform .2s ease
}

.ios13-segmented-control .option label span {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 2;
  -webkit-transition: all .2s ease;
  transition: all .2s ease;
  will-change: transform
}

.ios13-segmented-control .option input:checked+label::before,
.ios13-segmented-control .option input:checked+label::after {
  background: var(--background);
  z-index: 1
}

.ios13-segmented-control .option input:checked+label {
  cursor: default
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<body ontouchstart="">
  <main>
    <div class="ios13-segmented-control"> <span class="selection"></span>
      <div class="option"> <input type="radio" id="khar" name="sample" value="khar" checked> <label for="khar"><span>Khar</span></label></div>
      <div class="option"> <input type="radio" id="santacruz" name="sample" value="santacruz"> <label for="santacruz"><span>Santacruz</span></label></div>
      <div class="option"> <input type="radio" id="andheri" name="sample" value="andheri"> <label for="andheri"><span>Andheri</span></label></div>
    </div>
    <div class="khar selectt"> <br> <strong style="font-size: 24px; font-weight: 700; line-height:30px;">Khar</strong><br></div>
    <div class="santacruz selectt"> <br> <strong style="font-size: 24px; font-weight: 700; line-height:30px;">Santacruz</strong><br></div>
    <div class="andheri selectt"> <br> <strong style="font-size: 24px; font-weight: 700; line-height:30px;">Andheri</strong><br></div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      $(document).ready(function() {
        $('input[type="radio"]').each(function(index, element) {
          var inputValue = $(this).attr("value");
          var targetBox = $("." + inputValue);
          $(targetBox).hide();
        }).click(function() {
          var inputValue = $(this).attr("value");
          var targetBox = $("." + inputValue);
          $(".selectt").not(targetBox).hide();
          $(targetBox).show();
        });
      });
    </script>
  </main>
</body>
```

This has a drawback that items are not hidden instantly, so they can "blink" on load, so you may prefer the solution proposed by Philipp (but that one may be different for different versions of jQuery.. at least it depends on the implementation of `.hide()` and `.show()` methods.

Also this may need some refactoring though, like

```
$(document).ready(() => {
  $('input[type="radio"]').each((index, element) => {
    const inputValue = $(element).attr("value");
    const $targetBox = $("." + inputValue);
    $targetBox.hide();
    $(element).click(() => {
      // recalc inputValue and $targetBox if they may change in your case
      $(".selectt").not($targetBox).hide();
      $targetBox.show();
    })
  });
});
```